# How to change only empty cells in Excel using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

1. The code seems good to me but for some reason it doesn't work. He goes to 
   "else"
2. I want to change only the empty cells that are in a complete list

```
cls
$ExcelP = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\B.xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelP)

for ($counter = 0 ; $counter -lt 10 ; $counter ++) {

    if ($workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($counter, 1).value -eq "") {
        $workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($counter, 1).value = "yes"
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I think counter should begin at 1 and not 0. Excel doesn't have a row 0.

Comment: `Value` is a parameterized property, referencing it without an argument will never result in `""` - do `$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item($counter, 1).Text -eq ""` instead

Comment: Hi
Thanks for answering 
i tried.. It didn't help